# How do I edit the dotnet-format editorconfig file?

Tags: .net, windows, format

I installed dotnet-format from this github
https://github.com/dotnet/format

I am able to use it on my C# code, but I cannot find instructions anywhere on how to edit the `editorconfig` file

I don't know and cannot find the installation directory of dotnet-format, where this file may be

And in the official github instructions, there is not command line to open or edit the `editorconfig` settings

How do I change autoformat settings, how do I edit `editorconfig` file?

Also looking at the `editorconfig` that came with source code, why is there no `max_line_length` variable?

How can I set the max line length and break up lines into shorter lines automatically in C# code